# Stop fetching an association

Tags: doctrine-orm

I perform a simple query like this to fetch an association with episodes:

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery('
        SELECT p,e
        FROM AcmeDemoBundle:Place p
        LEFT JOIN p.episodes e
        WHERE p.id = :id'
        )
            ->setParameter('id',$id);
```

This is a simple asso:

```
 /**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Episode", mappedBy="place")
 */
protected $episodes;
```

This works well. Now, I don't want to fetch episodes, but simply the place object (and nothing else):

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery('
        SELECT p
        FROM AcmeDemoBundle:Place p
        LEFT JOIN p.episodes e
        WHERE p.id = :id'
        )
            ->setParameter('id',$id);
```

This is still loading episodes by lazy-loading. **Is there a way to avoid lazy-loading in that case?**

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery('
        SELECT p
        FROM AcmeDemoBundle:Place p
        WHERE p.id = :id'
        )
            ->setParameter('id',$id);

$query->setHint(Query::HINT_FORCE_PARTIAL_LOAD, true);
```

Comment: so what is going to happen when I access `$place->getEpisodes()`, will I get simply an empty collection? or an error would be thrown? [HINT_FORCE_PARTIAL_LOAD](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html?highlight=HINT_FORCE_PARTIAL_LOAD#query-hints) documentation is not very clear on explaning what's happening behind the scenes.  As in DQL example `episodes` is not explicitly loaded, isn't it a correct practise to keep proxied collection and rely on `fetch="LAZY"` configuration of the entities property?